# OpenSSL. Can not enable GOST engine

Tags: linux, openssl

Due to installation guide(https://github.com/gost-engine/engine/blob/master/INSTALL.md).

```
openssl version
>> OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022)
```

```
openssl version -e
>> ENGINESDIR: "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-3"
```

```
ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-3
>> afalg.so  gost.so  loader_attic.so  padlock.so
```

But  `openssl ciphers | grep "GOST"` gives me nothing

My /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf config:

```
[openssl_def]
engines = engine_section

[engine_section]
gost = gost_section

[gost_section]
engine_id = gost
dynamic_path = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-3/gost.so
default_algorithms = ALL
CRYPT_PARAMS = id-Gost28147-89-CryptoPro-A-ParamSet
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the source of your OpenSSL binaries?  What is your Linux distribution/version?  There's a good chance your binaries were compiled without GOST support.  `openssl ciphers -v 'ALL:COMPLEMENTOFALL'` will probably emit a few more ciphers than just `openssl ciphers`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle binaries in ```/usr/bin/openssl``` grepping your command also didnt give any result